# How to set default value to listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to set a background to the default value in a list, Say the 1st list Item as default.

I had set the property as setSlection(-1), but it doesn't work my list value does not show the item as selected.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Problem resolved :)

Used the following code,

```
private void setListviewSelection(final ListView list, final int pos, final int notselectedpos1, final int notselectedpos2) {
    list.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            list.setSelection(pos);
            View v = list.getChildAt(pos);
            View v1 = list.getChildAt(notselectedpos1);
            View v2 = list.getChildAt(notselectedpos2);

            if (v != null) {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_select);
                v1.setBackgroundResource(0);
                v2.setBackgroundResource(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Find  this code from stack overflow itself but mistake closed the link that's why not able to provide the link sorry for that. :(

Answer (score 0):

Set a background for your list item when you inflate it from an xml file.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt but i am not inflating the item from xml. I filled the list view using array adapter of string